# ListView not updating – error in ListViewDataSource.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently displaying an iOS application using the React Native framework. For allowing the user to choose an available Bluetooth LE device I use a RefreshableListView (NPM package: react-native-refreshable-listview) component which uses the ListView component supplied by React. As I use the list a second time (my application has an offline mode) I put it into a separate component and pass the available devices in using properties. The component is updated in the method `componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProperties)`, as shown below.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProperties)
{
    if (newProperties.devices !== undefined)
    {
        if (newProperties.devices.length > 0)
        {
            alert("length: " + newProperties.devices.length); // the expected result is shown by this statement
            this.setState
            (
                {
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newProperties.discoveredDevices)
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the list view is not updated due to the following error (captured using Google Chrome's debugging tool):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object    ListViewDataSource.js:202
```

For avoiding this error I have tried to initialize the array as shown below:

```
componentDidMount: function()
{
    this.setState
    (
        {
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(new Array())
        }
    );
}
```

However, this has not solved the issue. Initializing the array with static data (done by the method `componentDidMount`) does not fix the error too.

I appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version (0.5.0 RC 0) of React Native solved this issue.